# Regex: Match and delete 2 words before and after the specified word

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

This is the line:

`I love you and George loves IOANA but also Mihai is my enemy.`

I want to match 2 words before IOANA, and also 2 words after IOANA

**The Output should be:**

`I love you and IOANA Mihai is my enemy.`

I believe my regex must be upgrade a little bit, as to work:

SEARCH: `(^.*)(?s)(\w+{2}IOANA\w+{2})(.*)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: Match and delete 2 words before and after the specified word](https://superuser.com/questions/1686766/regex-match-and-delete-2-words-before-and-after-the-specified-word)

Comment: was a mistake, sorry, don't know how did I post the same question twice. So I delete the duplicate question.

Comment: What is a word for you? Only alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]`, alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, word character `\w`, everything that is not a space or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\S+ ){2}(IOANA)(?: \S+){2}`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    \S+         # 1 or more non space character
                # a space
){2}        # end group, must appear twice
(IOANA)     # group 1
(?:         # non capture group
                # a space
    \S+         # 1 or more non space character
){2}        # end group, must appear twice
```

I guess, here, that you means words are composed with non spaces characters.

- If, for you, word contains only letters and digits, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead of `\S+`.
- If, for you, word contains only letters and soeme punctuation like `'`, use `[a-zA-Z']+` instead of `\S+`.

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much !